# Angular 6 + SASS Folder Structure

Tags: angular, sass, angular6, directory-structure

What is the best Folder structure we can maintain for large project ( More than one page ).I am a beginner for sass and angular.please help me to get understand about folder structure.

Comment: Its totally upto your requirements, But I would suggest you to go with an Angular standard guide one sass file per component and one Global level Sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take of a well structured, organized and scaleable architecture for Angular solutions:

```
- app
  - core
    - guards
    - interceptors
    - models
    - services [self-provide in root, hence no need for a CoreModule]
      - auth
      - http
      - storage
  - features
    - heroes
      - components [pure presentation components, get data from page attributes]
      - pages [routed components, get data from services, send to components via attributes]
      - services [if only used in this feature]
      - models [if only used in this feature]
      - heroes-routing.module.ts
      - heroes.module.ts
  - shared
    - components [footer, header, calendar, dropdowns etc.]
    - directives
    - pipes
    - validators
    - shared.modules.ts [require CommonModule, FormsModule etc.]
  - app-routing.module.ts
  - app.component.html
  - app.module.ts
- assets
  - fonts
  - i18n
  - icon
  - images
```

Inspiration reference [Planning the Architecture of your Angular App, feb. 2019](https://itnext.io/planning-the-architecture-of-your-angular-app-a4840bfec13b)

Comment: thank you.its useful. I'll go through this structure.

Comment: @JesúsLópez I included the essential parts to the answer now

Comment: @BjarneGerhardt-Pedersen, deleted comment

Answer (score 1):

You should have a global sass file and then a component specific sass file for every component you have so that you can customize your desired style component by component. That way the project will be neat and easy to maintain.